# jquery contains not find previous class

Tags: jquery, contains

```
<div id='id1' class="mainDiv">Something</div>
<div class="dispatch" id="dis1">Dispatch</div><table><tr><td>Just</td><td>a table</td></tr></table>  
<div class='orderDiv'>Something else</div>  

<div id='id2' class="mainDiv">Something</div>
<div class="dispatch" id="dis2">Dispatch</div><table><tr><td>Just</td><td>a table</td></tr></table>  
<div class='orderDiv'>KEYWORD</div>  

<div id='id3' class="mainDiv">Something</div>
<div class="dispatch" id="dis3">Dispatch</div><table><tr><td>Just</td><td>a table</td></tr></table>  
<div class='orderDiv'>Something else</div>
```

I would like to have id1 and id3 set to display:none by searching for the NON-Existence of "KEYWORD".

I tried

```
$(".orderDiv")
    .not(':contains("KEYWORD")')
    .prevAll('.mainDiv:first')
    .css('display','none');
```

but this will only make `id1` invisible.

**UPDATE:**
All JSFiddle worked thanks, but it won't work with my original html structure which I now updated above. Also would be great to have dis1 and dis3 also hidden.

Comment: Only id1 and id3 you want to hide

Comment: Have updated my answer, this should work with your new structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) function:

```
$('.mainDiv').filter(function() {
    return !$(this).next('.orderDiv:contains(KEYWORD)').length;
}).hide();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FGcm4/)

If you only want to show the matching main div and order div, you can also chain on the following to the end:

```
.next('.orderDiv').hide();
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FGcm4/1/)

**Update as per your edit**

```
var divs = $('.orderDiv').not(':contains(KEYWORD)')

divs.each(function() {
    var div = $(this);
    div.hide()
        .prev('table').hide()
        .prev('.dispatch').hide()
        .prev('.mainDiv').hide();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/FGcm4/6/)

[If you just want to hide the mainDiv and dispatch](http://jsfiddle.net/peteng/FGcm4/7/)

Comment: Any idea why `$('.orderDiv:contains(KEYWORD)').show().prev('.mainDiv').show();` won't work to display the .mainDiv of the found KEYWORD (assuming its display was set to none before)?

Comment: beacause mainDiv is not the prev of orderDiv, you would have to do `$('.orderDiv:contains(KEYWORD)').show().prev('table').prev('.dispatch').prev('.mainDiv').show();`

Comment: Oh ok thanks but if my structure would change by any html-tag it wouldn't be right anymore. Is there a way to find the last class .mainDiv searching from the Keyword-Match?

Comment: In that case I would wrap each row in a div then you can do `$('.orderDiv:contains(KEYWORD)').show().parent().children('.mainDiv')`

Comment: Thanks but it will show the wrong .mainDiv as well http://jsfiddle.net/FGcm4/11/ (and unforunatley can't change the div structure - is a closed system)

Answer (score 0):

this will hide id1 and id3

```
    $(".orderDiv").not(':contains("KEYWORD")').prevAll('.mainDiv').not(':eq(1)').each(function()
         {
         $(this).css('display','none')
      });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Amit12x/NW2ws/)